# regular expression in php to extract image src from following html code

Tags: php, regex

i need regular expression in php to extract image src from following html code

```
<img class=" wp-image " width="300" height="218" alt="anything" src="image url"></img>
```

Comment: [And the pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: You need to do research before posting a question

Answer (score 1):

You should use an HTML parser for this. Nevertheless, you can do it using regex with something like this:

```
<img[^>\/]*src=("(?:[^\"]*)"|'(?:[^\']*)')
```

The image url would be in capture group 1.

Edit: If you also want to get unqouted src's you can use this:

```
<img[^>\/]*src=("(?:[^\"]*)"|'(?:[^\']*)'|(?:[^=<>\s\"\'`]+))
```

Comment: you are not covering without quoted src-links like `src=image.png`

Comment: @Atul Gupta thanks, I didn't even know that's valid HTML